# I need to declare a variable twice in the same "equation"

Tags: java

So I have this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final double life = 100;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter a value to damage the ennemy.");
    double attack = input.nextDouble();
    double life = life - attack;

    System.out.println("The ennemy has" + life + "left");
```

And im trying to make the life variable basically update into a new life variable that has a different value. But the program says i can't declare the same local variable twice... How Could I make it work, without make varaibel "life1, life2 etc..."

Thanks!

Comment: Don't declare life as final, if you want to use it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign new value to the variable:

```
life = life - attack;
```

Or even:

```
life -= attack;
```

Answer (score 0):

You re-use the same variable without declaring the type again:

```
life = life - attack;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the final from the first double.  Then instead of redeclaring the double later `double life` just do `life = life - attack`